# Assets folder for unit tests not copied

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to mock some data I used from assets in a library. So, as it is in the new Android Studio IDE with gradle. I used the test folder to write unit tests that run on the JVM and not the `androidTests` that run on a device. Everything looks great apart from the detail that assets are not copied to its respective build folder, in this case `build/intermediates/bundles/qa/debug/assets`. That means when I try to find my folder using `context.getAssets()` I can't.

Here it is the relevant stuff from my build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode theCode
        versionName myName
    }

    publishNonDefault true

    productFlavors {
        integration {

        }
        qa {

        }
    }
}
```

And for the Android build tools plugin I am using the version `1.3.1` just in case that can help.

Comment: Here it is a bug report for it in the Android tools tracker https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=184855

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Not yet, I just implemented other thing that didn't need the asset and I stopped having this problem in my project. Quite annoying though.

Comment: Hmm... I wrote a gradle  task to copy... Still looking for a straightforward fix....